# How to capture logs in tomcat when the server cpu and memory usage go high?

Tags: linux, tomcat

I deployed my application on the Linux tomcat server. i that server i have a performance issues, CPU and memory usage going to high.

I want a tool to capture tomcat logs at that peak time.

So, Please anyone suggest a tool like that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you know roughly when this happens? You could write a script to output memory output to a file every x minutes, hours, etc. A cronjob can call the script. When the system runs out of memory go check the file.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil thanks for your reply. I don't know when the spike is coming. Using some functionality, the spike is coming. I don't know when it's coming(depending on users usage). Please let me know any tools to record logs when CPU and memory suddenly get spike.